# Match a block of lines starting with a specific charecter in python

Tags: python, regex, multiline

I would like to search through a block of text and match the lines starting with a specific character in python- but want to stop as soon as that rule is broken.

For example, in the following text: (starting with asterisks)

---

* point one

* point two

** point two.one

* last point three

But here is a text in between

* four

---

I would like to stop the search as soon as encountering the non-bulleted text. I.e. the search/find should return only the text up to "* last point three".

I have been trying with various regex but with no luck. The closest I have got so far is

r'(^[*(**)].*)'

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

tjr

Comment: First: your example text doesn't appear to jibe with your intended goal -- should "three" be followed by a newline? If so, you should edit your post.  Second:  is your goal simply to find lines that don't begin with some number of asterisks?

Comment: Thanks jstevenco. Fixed the post. The goal is not to find lined don't begin with asterisks. Instead, find the ones with asterisks but stop as soon as some text interrupts that flow.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex to get those blocks:

```
^(?:\*+[^*\n]*?\n*(?=\*))*\*+[^*\n]*?(?:\n|$)(?!\*)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tH0oP1/1)

Comment: Glad it works, please consider accepting the answer (and upvoting if it proved helpful to you).

Answer (score 0):

You mean this,

```
re.findall(r'^(?s)\\*[^\n]*(?:\n\\\*[^\n]*)*', s)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jX5qS9/1)

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is simply to match up to the first point in the stream where the condition is not true, it seems like the most concise way to express this is

```
>>> pattern = r'^(?s)\*[^\n]*(?:\n+\*[^\n]*)*'

>>> target = """* point one
...
... * point two
...
... ** point two.one
...
... * last point three
...
... But here is a text in between
...
... * four
... """
>>> m=re.search(pattern,target)
>>> m.group(0)
'* point one\n\n* point two\n\n** point two.one\n\n* last point three'
```